# I installed Windows 7 after Ubuntu, how do I get the Grub menu back?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, bootloader, cd-image

I want to install Windows7 on my system with pre-installed Ubuntu 11.10 to play some games in my relax time.

But after installing Windows7 over Ubuntu my computer doesn't show OS chooser (GRUB) in the beginning of system startup.

Now I've lost my Ubuntu installation disk but I still have its .iso file. I can't, or don't want, to burn it to a CD/DVD?

Is there any way that I can use that .iso image to repair system startup without need to burn that CD again?

Comment: Please correct your title. You want to repair boot for using both operating that are installed.

Comment: Can I run grub from within windows 7, may be a better title.

Comment: Windows will wipe out grub once you install it on a machine, that is why it is recommended to install Windows first then Ubuntu. But there is of course a fix for this, you can try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or simply install grub again but to do this, you need to install the Ubuntu ISO to a USB drive if you don't want to burn it to a CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to install duel OS but If you install windows after Ubuntu Grub will be affected. Grub is a booting system of Linux base system. You can follow above steps or you can do just the following....

To fix booting problem you can install a program 'EasyBCD' in Windows.
Download it [here](http://download.cnet.com/EasyBCD/3000-2094_4-10556865.html)

Follow these steps to restore GRUB when after installing **EasyBCD**:

```
- Launch the program and select ADD NEW ENTRY from the EasyBCD Toolbox

- Select the 'Linux/BSD' from the operating systems column

- Choose GRUB (Legacy) under type and Click on the ADD ENTRY icon

- Choose YES to the restart prompt
```

GRUB will be displayed after the restart which will detect the Ubuntu partition for you to be able to boot into Ubuntu

Comment: I think, he said, he has already Windows installed. Thanks for the EasyBCD part

Comment: Thanx for this great solution Kaktarua.

Answer (score 0):

You could only try to get the .iso image onto a USB Stick. For this, you can use every operating system. (For more information about this click [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), look below to see the steps for copying Ubuntu onto a USB stick)

The USB stick is like a normal CD, but it is much faster.

Comment: All you need is a USB stick with 1 GB or more and another PC.